# css-how to make a table cell as scroll content if label in the cell is static?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a table in which I should display dynamic text in one cell. That cell already has label that is fixed.

```
printf( '<td ><strong>Comment:</strong> <span>%s</span></td>',$info['comment'] ) ;
```

Here "comment" is label. Highlighting between `<strong></strong>`

The value of comment maybe a word or multiple line will update dynamically.

If it is a word or one line, it should be displayed as simple text.

But if it is multiple lines, it should be a scrolling content without changing width of cell.

I tried with `<div class="scrollable">`.With css,

```
div.scrollable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

But the problem is the label and text is not on the same line.

I would like to display label and text on the same line in the table cell.
And also scrollable content for multiple line with same cell width.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here are the requirements:  1.Should display dynamic content in `<td>` as simple text..                                                                              2.The vertical scroller should come if the text is mulitiline text but with same width and height of the `<td>`...                                         3.The `<td>` which I have to display the above said text has a constant label(may be "comment:") `comment: our dynamic text here`,so scrolling is only for text.

Comment: No it is not `th`..it is in `td` only..`<td>comment:%s</td>`.that `%s` will have text using php.